# iPhone Image slideshow

Tags: iphone, objective-c, slideshow

I want to create a slideshow on iphone. I don't know if there is already a sample code or a lib that already do that.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

Joe Hewitt who created the Facebook iPhone app open sourced the code he wrote to create the Facebook application. Most notable is his image viewer that he created. I am certain if you checkout his work you can find what you are looking for. His project lives on github.

https://github.com/facebook/three20/

Reference to his work from his website:

http://joehewitt.com/post/the-three20-project/

Answer (score 2):

Check out the WWDC 2010 Session entitled "Designing Apps with Scroll Views."

The source code is here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html

And this is a handy image-slicing tool:

http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/10/cutting-large-images-into-tiles-for.html

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to show different pictures one by one, you can simply use, for example, NSTimer, that will change content of your image view. It doesn't need any lib.