# Programmatically scroll a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, scroll

I have a `UIScrollView` which has several views. When a user flicks their finger, the view scrolls to the right or left depending on the direction of the finger flick. Basically my code works in a way similar to the iPhone photo app.  Now, is there a way that I can programmatically do the same thing so that I end up with a slideshow that runs on its own with a click of a button and a configurable pause between each scroll?

How do you really do slideshows with `UIScrollView`?

Answer (score 426, accepted):

You can scroll to some point in a scroll view with one of the following statements in Objective-C

```
[scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(x, y) animated:YES];
```

or Swift

```
scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: x, y: y), animated: true)
```

See the [guide "*Scrolling the Scroll View Content*" from Apple as well](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/ScrollingViewContent/ScrollingViewContent.html).

To do slideshows with `UIScrollView`, you arrange all images in the scroll view, set up a repeated timer, then `-setContentOffset:animated:` when the timer fires.

But a more efficient approach is to use 2 image views and swap them using transitions or simply switching places when the timer fires. See [iPhone Image slideshow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631170/iphone-image-slideshow) for details.

Comment: Cool. Yes, I did find that setContentOffset works but really wanted this to happen in animated way. 'animated:YES' did the trick.

Comment: Just complementing the answer, to move horizontally to the next "page" in UIScrollView (assuming you are coding for iPhone), for the x parameter use `(myScrollView.contentOffset.x +320)`.

Comment: @niraj thanks dude...in `(myScrollView.contentOffset.x +320)` lies the key!

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but UIScrollView's `contentOffset:` will offset the contentSize as well, which may not be desirable. To only scroll, you may want to use `scrollRectToVisible:`.

Comment: Do no use C helper functions like `CGPointMake` in Swift. Simply build a Swift struct directly: `CGPoint(x: 0, y: 44)`

Comment: [scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height), animated:YES];
when i'm adding this it is slightly scrolled upwards initially. Can you give me a fix @kennytm ?

Answer (score 42):

If you want control over the duration and style of the animation, you can do:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0f delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
    scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(x, y);
} completion:NULL];
```

Adjust the duration (`2.0f`) and options (`UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear`) to taste!

Answer (score 20):

I'm amazed that this topic is 9 years old and the actual straightforward answer is not here!

What you're looking for is `scrollRectToVisible(_:animated:)`.

Example:

```swift
extension SignUpView: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(textField.frame, animated: true)
    }
}
```

What it does is exactly what you need, and it's far better than hacky `contentOffset`

> This method scrolls the content view so that the area defined by rect
>   is just visible inside the scroll view. If the area is already
>   visible, the method does nothing.

From: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619439-scrollrecttovisible

Comment: good solution, but contentOffset gives more control over where exactly you want to scroll

Answer (score 12):

Another way is

```
scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(x,y);
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as the accepted answer. And `CGPoint` should be `CGPointMake`.

Comment: I like simple answers like this one.

Comment: Actually, this is not the same as the accepted answer.  The accepted answer has an option of animated, which some apps might want to have set to YES.

Answer (score 11):

With Animation in Swift

```
scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(x, y), animated: true)
```

Answer (score 6):

Swift 3

```
let point = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 200) // 200 or any value you like.
scrollView.contentOffset = point
```

Answer (score 3):

```
scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: y, y: x), animated: true)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[Scrollview setContentOffset:CGPointMake(x, y) animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    board=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.height, 80)];
    board.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
    [self.view addSubview:board];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{


    NSString *str=@"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    index=1;
    for (int i=0; i<20; i++)
    {
        UILabel *lbl=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-50, 15, 50, 50)];
        lbl.tag=i+1;
        lbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",[str characterAtIndex:arc4random()%str.length]];
        lbl.textColor=[UIColor darkGrayColor];
        lbl.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        lbl.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:40];
        lbl.layer.borderWidth=1;
        lbl.layer.borderColor=[UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
        [board addSubview:lbl];
    }

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self selector:@selector(CallAnimation) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    NSLog(@"%d",[board subviews].count);
}


-(void)CallAnimation
{

    if (index>20) {
        index=1;
    }
    UIView *aView=[board viewWithTag:index];
    [self doAnimation:aView];
    index++;
    NSLog(@"%d",index);
}

-(void)doAnimation:(UIView*)aView
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:10 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear  animations:^{
        aView.frame=CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.height, 15, 50, 50);
    }
                     completion:^(BOOL isDone)
     {
         if (isDone) {
             //do Somthing
                        aView.frame=CGRectMake(-50, 15, 50, 50);
         }
     }];
}
```

Comment: Please consider adding some text to your answer, not only pure code

Answer (score -1):

Here is another use case which worked well for me.

1. User tap a button/cell.
2. Scroll to a position just enough to make a target view visible.

Code: **Swift 5.3**

```swift
// Assuming you have a view named "targeView"
scrollView.scroll(to: CGPoint(x:targeView.frame.minX, y:targeView.frame.minY), animated: true)
```

As you can guess if you want to scroll to make a bottom part of your target view visible then use maxX and minY.