# UIScrollView. How to use the scroll bar on the side?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4, ios-simulator

I'm working with Xcode developing for iOS using a `UIScrollView`. I got the scrollview working just fine.

But my issue/question is dealing with how to use the scrollbar on the side of the scrollview:

For example, I have dynamically created 2000 buttons inside the scrollview, in the simulator. The buttons are lined up vertically, so I have to scroll down to see all of the buttons. I do not want to simulate scrolling 30 to 40 times in order to get to the 1500th button.

I have the code to go to the last button, and to scroll to top. But I was wondering if there is anyone that can give insights on whether I can use the scroll bar on the side of that scrollview in order to help me navigate the scrolling better.

[image]

Comment: This is not a scroll bar, it is a scroll indicator. It is just like a scroll bar, but in a sense it is "read-only": end users can see it, but they cannot drag it, like they do on desktops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That bad boy isn't a scroll bar.  It's simply a visual indicator of the current location.  There are ways to [scroll programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234875/programmatically-scroll-a-uiscrollview), but I'm not sure that's really what you want to do.

Comment: Wow. That fooled me. I thought that was a regular scroll bar. Thanks.