# Scroll view scrolling up & down on button click

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios6, uiscrollview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Programmatically scroll a UIScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234875/programmatically-scroll-a-uiscrollview)

Currently, I am developing an App in which I have `UIScrollView` and some buttons are programatically inserted in `scroll view.Scrolling` of these added buttons work fine for me. but I want to add two 
more button & on one button click `scroll view scrolling` to bottom side and display bottom last

buttons and when I click on second button it scroll to top side and it show top most button. I have tried so much but can't succeeded. How can I solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: On button click you set the contentoffset.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
scrollView=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 400)];
scrollView.backgroundColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor];
scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320, 500);
scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator=YES;
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
```

If Scroll Size is known then we can set the button click event

```
-(void)buttonCkicked:(UIButton*)sender
{
    if (sender.tag==1001) {
        [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 100) animated:YES];
    }
    if (sender.tag==1002) {
        [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This may solve ur pbm

```
-(IBAction) clickfirstbutton 
{
   [scrollview setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, (intvalue to the positon of two buttons)) animated:TRUE];
}

-(IBAction) clicksecondbutton
{
   [scrollview setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:TRUE];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
-(IBAction)btn1_Clicked:(id)sender{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    yourScrollView.frame=CGRectMake(0, -scrollView.contentSize.height + 360, 320, scrollView.contentSize.height);/// set y (starting point) with your scrollview height
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

-(IBAction)btn2_Clicked:(id)sender{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    yourScrollView.frame=CGRectMake(0,0 , 320, scrollView.contentSize.height);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```