# Is there a way to make UIScrollView stop and bounce at arbitrary position

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a long horizontal UIScrollView and I want to make it stop and bounce in some special cases. Is there a way to do that without changing the content lenght?

EDIT: I don't want it to scroll to a position, I just want it to act as if it hit its boundary somewhere.

Comment: I think you should read this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234875/programmatically-scroll-a-uiscrollview

Comment: You can override the resting location through `scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:` but you can't affect the bouncing afaik.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable the scroll view to bounce using:

```
//scroll is an instance of UIScrollView
scroll.alwaysBounceVertical/Horizontal = YES;
```

Comment: I am currently stopping the scrolling with scrollViewDidScroll: and then setting scrollView.contentOffset.x. That prevents bouncing :P Is there another way to stop the view from scrolling?

Comment: scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width,scrollView.frame.size.height);

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scrollRectToVisible:animated:` method if you want to scroll to a particular position