# unable to hide button after completing moving in collectionView

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview

i am scrolling at left and right side in collectionView by click button horizontally, it works well, but i do not know how to hide button when is no more item in a side of collectionView. the previewButton will hide when no more item in left side and the next button will hide when no more item in right side. here is code of left and right button

```
let arrow_leftBtn: UIButton = {
    let btn = UIButton()
    btn.setImage(UIImage(named: "arrow_left"), for: .normal)

    btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(arrowLeftBtnClick), for: .touchUpInside)
    return btn

}()

func arrowLeftBtnClick() {
    let collectionBounds = self.collectionView?.bounds
    let contentOffset = CGFloat(floor((self.collectionView?.contentOffset.x)! - (collectionBounds?.size.width)!))
    self.moveToFrame(contentOffset: contentOffset)
}

let arrow_rightBtn: UIButton = {
    let btn = UIButton()
    btn.setImage(UIImage(named: "arrow_right"), for: .normal)


    btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(arrowRightBtnClick), for: .touchUpInside)
    return btn


}()


func arrowRightBtnClick() {

    let collectionBounds = self.collectionView?.bounds
    let contentOffset = CGFloat(floor((self.collectionView?.contentOffset.x)! + (collectionBounds?.size.width)!))
    self.moveToFrame(contentOffset: contentOffset)
}

func moveToFrame(contentOffset : CGFloat) {

    let frame: CGRect = CGRect(x : contentOffset ,y : self.collectionView!.contentOffset.y ,width : self.collectionView!.frame.width,height : self.collectionView!.frame.height)
    self.collectionView?.scrollRectToVisible(frame, animated: true)


}


func setupLeftAndRightArrow() {



    view.addSubview(arrow_leftBtn)
    view.addSubview(arrow_rightBtn)

    view.addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|-20-[v0(20)]", views: arrow_leftBtn)
    view.addConstraintsWithFormat("V:|-180-[v0(20)]|", views: arrow_leftBtn)

    view.addConstraintsWithFormat("H:[v0(20)]-30-|", views: arrow_rightBtn)
    view.addConstraintsWithFormat("V:|-180-[v0(20)]|", views: arrow_rightBtn)
}
```

[image]

Comment: You want to hide next and previous button which used to scroll `UICollectionView`?

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29362915/uiscrollview-with-left-and-right-arrows-in-ios

Comment: the previewButton will hide when no more item in left side and the next button will hide when no more item in right side

Comment: @user3589771 i edit my question please check it again

Comment: @user3589771 i added image of project please check it

Comment: If `UICollectionViewItem` has full-width use collection view item count `(array.count-1)*screen_width==currentcontentOffset` for rightbutton and `0==contentOffset` for left side button. [Check this answer for swipe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31857825/3589771)

Comment: @user3589771 please look at image which i added newly. it is scrolling by button click but i do not know how to hide the button when scrolling is finish

Comment: We have only option to find scroll end or not, Use `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` instead of `scrollViewDidScroll` method. Still, it's not what you want kindly update your question. You didn't mention any thing related to scroll to hide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement `UICollectionViewDelegate` method:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    arrow_rightBtn.isHidden = (indexPath.row == collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) - 1)
    arrow_leftBtn.isHidden = (indexPath.row == 0)
}
```

This will hide the `arrow_rightBtn` when last cell is visible and hide `arrow_leftBtn` when first cell is visible.

Comment: come to here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48970198/how-to-detect-one-button-in-tableview-cell/48971060#48971060

Comment: @QuietIslet Can you please explain the link you provided? I don't understand.

Comment: How to detect just one button in tableview cell, here detect multiple button, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48970198/how-to-detect-one-button-in-tableview-cell?noredirect=1#comment84948065_48970198

Comment: @QuietIslet I've answered your question in the provided link. Have a look and let me know if you still face any issues regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use collectionView delegate method to detect first last cells

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplayCell cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == dataSource.count - 1 {
        // Last cell is visible
        leftBtn.isHidden = false
        rightBtn.isHidden =true
    } else if indexPath.row == 0 {
        // First cell is visible
        leftBtn.isHidden = true
        rightBtn.isHidden = false
    } else {
        //for others cells
        leftBtn.isHidden = false
        rightBtn.isHidden =false

    }
}
```

Comment: qustion is related to hide the left and right button on swipe

Comment: @Baig thanks to try. i added image of project please check it

Comment: I understand, you can hide left button when first cell of collectionView is visible, similarly hide right button when last cell of collectionView is visible

Comment: @AzmalTech please see the updated answer, may it give you idea