# How to open image files using one view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I can't seem to find any code online to switch views automatically. But I want my images to open automatically in a view one after another. Any advise?

---

I would like to open the image individually in each view, and kill the previous view when viewing the current view. I do not wish to use any slideshow. Hope you guys can advise me.

Comment: Do u want to create a slideshow type... ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631170/iphone-image-slideshow in this link you will get all things.

Answer (score 2):

Add this line to viewDidLoad(This one is for the situation when you have your images stored in document directory of your project **Dynamic**):

```
    slideShowTimer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 3.0 target: self selector:@selector(changeImageSlide) userInfo: nil repeats:YES];
```

the `changeImageSlide` method:

```
- (void) changeImageSlide
{
    totalNoOfImages=[copyOf_myGlobleArrayOfImageIds count];
    if (imageCounter>=totalNoOfImages-1) 
    {
        imageCounter=0;
    }
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg",[copyOf_myGlobleArrayOfImageIds objectAtIndex:imageCounter]];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fullImgNm=[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithString:str]];
    //=(3*imageCounter+4)%25;
    [mainSlideShowImageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fullImgNm]];
    [mainSlideShowImageView setTag:[[copyOf_myGlobleArrayOfImageIds objectAtIndex:imageCounter] intValue]];     
    imageCounter++;
}
```

## OR

use the following(it's for the situation when your images are in the resource folder of your project and you have added them to your project **static**):

```
//MAIN SIDE SHOW TASK
//while fetching names from database need to impliment another mutable array ref:information provider
NSArray *imageNames=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1.jpg",
                     @"2.jpg",
                     @"3.jpg",
                     @"4.jpg",
                     @"5.jpg",
                     @"6.jpg",
                     @"7.jpg",
                     @"8.jpg",
                     @"9.jpg",
                     @"10.jpg",
                     @"11.jpg",
                     @"12.jpg",
                     @"13.jpg",
                     @"14.jpg",
                     @"15.jpg",nil];

int limit=[imageNames count];
NSMutableArray *tempNames=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i=0; i<limit; i++) {
    NSString *str= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[imageNames objectAtIndex:i]];
    [tempNames addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:(NSString *)str]];
}

NSArray *images=tempNames;
NSLog(@"name array=======%@",images);
mainSlideShowImageView.animationImages=images;
mainSlideShowImageView.animationDuration = 75.00; 
mainSlideShowImageView.animationRepeatCount = 0; //infinite
[mainSlideShowImageView startAnimating];
//MAIN SlIDE SHOW TASK COMPLETE
```