# Make a slide show on iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, slideshow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone Image slideshow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631170/iphone-image-slideshow)

I want to do a simple slideshow with 6 images but i have any idea on how to do that. It's with UIPageControl ? there are a tutorial ?

Comment: Do you mean UIPageViewController?

Comment: Might want to look into UIScrollView. That would probably do what you want. If not, we'll need more details.

Answer (score 0):

If its UIPageViewController, in your root view controller, call the method

```
- (void)setViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers direction:(UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection)direction animated:(BOOL)animated completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion
```

Call this method in a timer.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the way you want to show the images. There are ways to acheive this result, NSTimer,[UIPageControl with ScrollView](http://sugartin.info/2012/01/21/image-sliding-page-by-page-uiscrollview-auto-scrolling-like-image-slider/)(image Change towards right hand side direction)     ,[ImageView.animationImages method](http://appsamuck.com/day2.html)(change is instant with no animation).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a UIScrollViewController. So, when you have, for example, an array of image names, you can do something like

```
for(NSString *imageName in imageNames){
    UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]];
    image.frame = CGRectMake([imageNames indexOf:imageName] * SCREENWIDTH, 0, SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT);
    [scrollView addSubview:image];
    [image release];
}
```

Be sure to select the Paging Enabled option for the scrollView in Interface Builder. Now you can do a slideshow with your fingers. If you want it to be automatic you can also use

```
[self performSelector:@selector(slide) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
```

And in another function

```
-(void)slide{
    [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(/*calculate X axis offset*/,0) animated:YES]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

even you can do it with nstimer